# How to set rails param as current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I scaffolded a resource in rails that has two params, amount and creator. Instead of letting the user set creator I want :creator to be set by the logged in users ID (current_user). How do I set :creator to the current users ID?

Comment: So, did you try setting the property to `current_user` from whatever the method is updating this inside controller?

Comment: Oh that did it. I really need to sleep more thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge` an attribute to `params` before it is passed as an argument.

```
@invoice = Invoice.new invoice_params.merge(creator: current_user)
@invoice.save
```

Or set `:creator` directly

```
@invoice = Invoice.new invoice_params
@invoice.creator = current_user
@invoice.save
```